# Does the Sword Master achievement actually need to do something less than 20 times?

Tags: steam, achievements, lost-ruins

For Sword Master, I got the Katana, then followed the Steam Guide that says to:

> slice up Totems' fireballs

But I think I only did it 10 or so times, instead of the 20 the achievement text says.

Am I right that the text is wrong? Or did I just miscount, and can I actually figure it out by myself?

[Steamdb](https://steamdb.info/app/1306630/stats/) says that there's the "StatSwordMaster" which probably counts the times I did the required action, but I don't know how to query that, [resetting just the achievement](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=2928878449) might not help if I can't return the counter to 0 as well? The [find](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/6gm81b/console_command_list/dircahh/) command is nice, but isn't helping me figure out what commands I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achievements that complete after an event happens enough times, might now give pop-ups at the halfway point?

It seems I did 11 the first time, when the pop-up happened. I checked my achievements, and since I was migrating from GOG just for Sword Master, I could easily tell that I had actually 0 achievements, not the 1 that would be Sword Master.

I stopped doing the tracked event and went exploring, died, respawned to do the event 9 more times, at which point I *actually* got the achievement.

Comment: It's been a while and I already have the achievements so I can't confirm, but I believe this is one of the rare games that actually counts achievement progress using the steam API. Half-life 2 also used it, and I really can't think of anything else other than those 2. The popup you saw was the progress notification, not the achievement itself. All of the "do something x times" achievements should have the same behavior.